# SVN: Throw out all old merge info

Tags: svn

I'm trying to merge my trunk into my branch so I can stay up to date.  However, at some point in the past someone did a merge incorrectly.  I was wondering if it's possible to throw all of the past merge info out and start over.  Something like "svn merge --re-merge" (obviously not a command, but I think it helps illustrate the idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the

```
--ignore-ancestry
```

flag which "causes the merging logic to mindlessly generate differences the same way that svn diff does, ignoring any historical relationships". From http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html

Answer (score 1):

Merge info is not versioned.  Just modify the property to contain what you want it to.

I googled MergeInfo and found this article.  I think it could help you out.

http://chrisoldwood.blogspot.com/2010/03/cleaning-up-svnmergeinfo-droppings.html

From Chris's article

> Deleting the MergeInfo Properties
>
> Now, if I interpret this post “Subversion merge reintegrate” correctly
>   then the point of the mergeinfo property is so that Subversion knows
>   what contributions have already been taken from other branches. The
>   fact that Subversion keeps updating the upper revision in the property
>   after each branch is merged reinforces my belief that this is an
>   optimisation of some sort. In theory then you could remove those
>   entries in the merginfo properties which reference dead branches. The
>   only fly-in-the-ointment is that you probably won’t find a mergeinfo
>   property with a single reference exactly because of the behaviour
>   outlined above. So what about deleting the whole mergeinfo property on
>   each file and folder?
>
> C:> svn propdel svn:mergeinfo –R